# Change font of back button on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I'm trying to change the font color of the text on my back button in my `UINavigationControllerBar`:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I get this error:

```
[_UIBarItemAppearance setTitleColor:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69aeb70'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this instead, default function available in iOS 5:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

[backbutton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [UIColor blackColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,
    [UIFont fontWithName:TEXTFONT size:16.0f],UITextAttributeFont,nil]
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS7+. Itgiawa's answer is working for it.

Answer (score 50):

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:(163.0f/255.0f) green:(0.0f) blue:(0.0f) alpha:1.0f] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowColor];
[attributes setValue:[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0, 0.0)] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

seems to work!

Comment: Way better solution to use the appearance options.  They work globally, or by class, or by instance.  Anyone coming here should use this answer instead.

Comment: Depends fully on the situation. I was working on a game and needed to change the font only temporally. ;-)

Comment: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cuprum-regular" size:14.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Its more dam perfectly change font

Answer (score 18):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                     [UIFont fontWithName:kDefaultFont size:16.0f],UITextAttributeFont,
                                                     nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: For IOS7, replace UITextAttributeFont with NSFontAttributeName

Comment: Working Perfectly on iOS8 , also i changed  UITextAttributeFont To  NSFontAttributeName and it worked also

Answer (score 6):

And the beautiful solution, iOS7+ (because of attribute names):

```
NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
[shadow setShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.750f]];
[shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
        NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24],
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1.0],
        NSShadowAttributeName: shadow,
} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution in Swift 4:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
[
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "MyriadPro-SemiboldCond", size: 16)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
], for: .normal)
```

Add this in AppDelegate and it'll be applied to all buttons in the app.

Comment: Seem to have a bug that only applies the font to the seconds time viewing the button. Seems to still exist in iOS 12.