# How to get UIBarButtonItem UIViewController?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a reference of `UIViewController`. From that reference i want to get references to all my navigation bar and bar button items and apply custom styles on them.

How can i achieve this on iOS 5?

Comment: I am not sure but see if u could do this. `yourviewcontrollerref.navigationcontroller.navigationItem` try this!!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6389991/377384

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that.

```
[backbutton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor blackColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIFont fontWithName:TEXTFONT size:16.0f],UITextAttributeFont,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: how do i fetch backbutton from UIViewController reference?

Comment: backbutton is just the name of UIBarButtonItem. You can name it whatever you want.

UIBarButtonItem *backbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]; That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: i don't have a reference to backbutton. i want to fetch it from viewcontroller reference

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your view controller has a navigation controller, you should be able to access the navigation bar and its items using the following code:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [myViewController.navigationController.navigationBar];
NSArray *navBarItems = navBar.items;
```

Comment: and how would i change the font for the back bar button item?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040699/change-font-of-back-button-on-uinavigationcontroller