# Change the font on the back button of a navigation controller under swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uinavigationcontroller

Swift 4, iOS 11.2.5 Xcode 9.2

Trying to change the font of the back button. Tried previous solutions found, but none seem to work under Swift 4, iOS 11.2.5 with my configuration, navigation controller within a tab bar controller.

Got this code, the first and last lines work, but the center three do not.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!]
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .normal)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .highlighted)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .focused)
navigationItem.title = "Filter \(titleSelection!) [shake to clear]"
```

[image]

This is in `viewDidLoad` method. Should this work?

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change font of back button on uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040699/change-font-of-back-button-on-uinavigationcontroller)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Swift 4, try this in **AppDelegate**.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
        
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green, NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)! ], for: .highlighted)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue, NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)! ], for: .focused)
        
        return true
}
```

In **ViewController**.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    self.title = "List"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!]

    // THE BELOW THREE LINES NOT WORKING.
 
    //navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .normal)

    //navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .highlighted)

    //navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .focused)

}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Had high hopes for this one too; but unfortunately didn't work for me either. I got some odd setup here I guess.

Comment: Yes, this worked! The secret to put the code in app delegate it seems!! Thanks!!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me across the app by adding to AppDelegate.

Answer (score 4):

You could change the font in the app delegate by doing something along these lines, this will change the font through out the whole app instead of in one viewcontroller though.

```
if let customFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20.0) {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFont], for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To make it working on iOS 13.0 you should use UINavigationBarAppearience. Here is what you can do in order to change font of ALL elements in the navigation bar:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!]
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = attributes
    navBarAppearance.buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = attributes
    navBarAppearance.doneButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = attributes

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .normal)
```

Try:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", size: 20)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 5** you can do it by these:

```
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)]
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Please note it will be effective for the **next** pushed view controller not the current one on the display, that's why it's very confusing!

Also, check the storyboard and select the navigation item of the **previous** view controller then type something in the **Back Button** (Inspector).